# Why $\frac{\varepsilon}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}$ converges in the sense of distributions to a constant times the Dirac delta

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, distribution-theory, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence

The integral of $f_\varepsilon(x)=\frac\varepsilon{x^2+\varepsilon^2}$ is the tan inverse, which is well behaved anywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, and so $f_\varepsilon$ is in $L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R})$. Its action as a distribution becomes:
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\varepsilon}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}\varphi(x) \, dx$ for any test function $\varphi$.

I use Lebesgue's DCT by noting that the set where the integrand does not converge to $0$ (when $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$) is merely countable. But of course this does not give me what I want, which is some constant times the delta. What is my mistake here?

Comment: You need to prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\varepsilon}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}\varphi(x) \, dx\to C\varphi(0)$ as $\varepsilon\to0^+$ for a suitable $C$.

Comment: You don't have an integrable dominating function in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prove that $\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\vp}{\varphi}$
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{\ep}(x)\vp(x)\,dx\to\pi\vp(0)$
as $\ep\to0^+$. But $f_\ep(x)=\ep^{-1}f_1(x/\ep)$ and so
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{\ep}(x)\vp(x)\,dx
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\vp(\ep y)}{y^2+1}\,dy.$$
As $\vp$ is a test function, this tends to $\pi\vp(0)$.
In a bit more detail,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\vp(\ep y)}{y^2+1}\,dy-
\pi\vp(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\vp(\ep y)-\vp(0)}{y^2+1}\,dy
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ep y\vp'(\xi_{\ep y})}{y^2+1}\,dy$$
where $\xi_{\ep y}$ is between $0$ and $\ep y$. If $\vp$ is supported in
$[-M,M]$ then this is bounded in absolute value by
$$2\ep C\int_0^{M/\ep}\frac{y}{y^2+1}\,dy=\ep C\ln(M^2/\ep^2+1)$$
for $C=\sup|\vp'(x)|$. This will tend to zero with $\ep$.

Comment: Ah! That rewrite was really important.. I did not see it. Thank you! Also: maybe it is essentially what you have done, but is it possible to use Lebesgue directly in your third integral from the top? As $y^2\geq 0$ we get the integrand less than the test which is less than a characteristic function of its support times its supremum norm (which is L1(R))?

Comment: Reason I ask is because I find the Lagrange approach a bit daunting

Answer (score 1):

Your function is $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\frac{1}{1+(x/\varepsilon)^2}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}f_1(\frac{x}{\varepsilon})$, so the integral over $x$ is $\varepsilon$-independent. Since $f_1\ge 0$ and $\int_\mathbb{R}f_1(x)dx$ is finite, $f_1=Kf$ for some PDF $f$ and finite $K>0$ you can find. For all "suitably well-behaved functions" $g(x)$ (working out what that means is an exercise), $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_\mathbb{R}f_\varepsilon(x)g(x)dx=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_\mathbb{R}f_1(x)g(\varepsilon x)dx=g(0)\int_\mathbb{R}f_1(x)dx=Kg(0).$$(The first $=$ makes a substitution, the second moves the limit inside the integral, and the third moves a constant outside.) As distributions, the $f_\varepsilon$ therefore have limit $K\delta(x)$.